# How to prove these 7 inequation about characteristic function?

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

In *Problems in Probability* by Shiryaev, Many problems about characteristic function are based on these inequalities? Does anybody have hints to prove some of them? Here's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa6tt.jpg). Thank you.

> Prove that any characteristic function $\varphi=\varphi(t)$ must satisfy the following inequalities:
>
> $$1-\operatorname{Re} \varphi(n t) \leq n\left[1-(\operatorname{Re} \varphi(t))^{n}\right] \leq n^{2}[1-\operatorname{Re} \varphi(t)], n=0,1,2, \ldots ;\tag{*}$$
>
> $$|\operatorname{Im} \varphi(t)|^{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}[1-\operatorname{Re} \varphi(2 t)] ; \quad 1-\operatorname{Re} \varphi(2 t) \geq 2(\operatorname{Re} \varphi(t))^{2}$$
>
> $$|\varphi(t)-\varphi(s)|^{2} \leq 4 \varphi(0)|1-\varphi(t-s)| ; \quad 1-|\varphi(2 t)|^{2} \leq 4\left[1-|\varphi(t)|^{2}\right]$$
>
> $$|\varphi(t)-\varphi(s)|^{2} \leq 2[1-\operatorname{Re} \varphi(t-s)]$$
>
> $$\frac{1}{2 h} \int_{t-h}^{t+h} \varphi(u) d u \leq(1+\operatorname{Re} \varphi(h))^{1 / 2}, t>0$$

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Here is one recent [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3789884/121671) that sheds more light to the problem you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution to the easiest one of them all:

$\operatorname{Im}(\phi)=\int\sin tx\mu(dx)$

Thus, by Jensen's inequality

$\Big|\operatorname{Im}(\phi)\Big|^2\leq\int\sin^2 tx\mu(dx)=\int \frac{1-\cos 2tx}{2}\,\mu(dx)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\int\cos 2tx\,\mu(dx))-\frac{1}{2}(1-\operatorname{Re}(\phi(2t))$

The otherwise are a little more challenging but require tricks like the one above. Also, notice that

$$\Big|\int\cos tx\,\mu(dx)\Big|\leq1$$

Using this, for instance also gives you the RHS of the first inequality:
$$n\Big(1-(\operatorname{Re}(\phi(t))^n\big)=n\big(1-\operatorname{Re}(\phi(t))\big)\big(1+\operatorname{Re}(\phi(t))+\ldots+\operatorname{Re}(\phi(t))^{n-1}\big)\leq n^2\big(1-\operatorname{Re}(\phi(t))\big)
$$
The right hand side of the same inequality suggest to see whether this holds:
$$
1-\cos n\alpha \leq n(1-\cos^n(\alpha))$$
for all $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

For $|\varphi(t)-\varphi(s)|^{2} \leq 2[1-\operatorname{Re} \varphi(t-s)]$, apply Schwarz inequality to the LHS, should be straight forward afterward.

Answer (score 0):

For $|\varphi(t)-\varphi(s)|^{2} \leq 2[1-\operatorname{Re} \varphi(t-s)]$ I have written the following.

I didn't use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. The main points used in my proof are:

1. $|E[X]| \leq E[|X|]$
2. $|e^{ix}| = 1$
3. If $g(x)$ is convex then $g(E[X])\leq E[g(X)]$.

Feel free to ask me anything. (Unfortunately, I don't know LaTeX good enough to write this yet).
[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1715202)

Comment: Thank you for your review! I hope the edit is okey.

Comment: Yes, it is better now.